# Virtualmin and ProFTPd - cannot connect/browse FTP

Tags: ftp, proftpd

I am using Virtualmin 3.99 with Pro FTP 1.33 on Centos 6.4.

I have added a virtual server but cannot connect to the home directory via FTP. I have checked the user setup and it is set for FTP and SSH and ProFTP is running. I can connect fine via SSH.

When I try to connect via Filezilla, everything looks like it has worked but in the remote site window I get the message "Not connected to any server"

From reading around it appears this is an issue to do with MLSD and certain FTP clients - I found a suggested fix of adding below to proftpd.conf but this hasn't done anything for me.

```
<IfModule mod_facts.c>
FactsAdvertise off
</IfModule>
```

There is no ProFTP log file in /var/log/proftpd/ (the directory is empty).

I also tried creating a new FTP user and again tried to connect but got exactly the same thing and, considering SSH works, it sounds like a ProFTP issue rather than permissions etc. I also have tried connecting from WinSCP and Coffee Free FTP to no avail.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was actually a NAT/ports issue - as Filezilla was using Passive mode I needed to open enough ports and then tell ProFTP which ports were in use.

I got the solution from http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/NAT.html and followed their advice and opened posts 60000:65535 on CSF firewall as well as added

```
PassivePorts 60000 65535
```

to /etc/proftpd.conf then restarted both ProFTPd and CSF firewall and it has worked - I can now browse directories etc as I needed.